# Firebase deploy, ignore all files but public folder

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to clean up my deployment process to Firebase, and need to ignore all files besides my `/dist` aka public folder when deploying files to the hosting. I believe it can be done via `ignore` setting in `firebase.json`, but I am not sure how to achieve it besides manually specifying all files.

example `.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      // ignore all other files besides dist folder here
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the glob `**` to [ignore any file or folder in an arbitrary sub-directory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#section-glob).

You can then un-ignore your `dist` folder with `!dist`

So your `firebase.json` file would look like:

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
        },
        "hosting": {
            "public": "dist",
            "ignore": [
                "**",
                "!dist/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [{
                "source": "**",
                "destination": "/index.html"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

## For newer versions of Firebase:

It appears that new versions of firebase don't allow for the above mentioned method, so instead just define the folders which should be ignored:

```
{
    "database": {
        "rules": "database.rules.json"
        },
        "hosting": {
            "public": "dist",
            "ignore": [
                "**/node_modules/**",
                "**/src/**",
                "**/public/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [{
                "source": "**",
                "destination": "/index.html"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can use the Firebase console to check how many files have been deployed:

1. Open your Firebase project's Hosting page and take note of the number of files.[image: Firebase Hosting dashboard]
2. Run the command `$ tree dist/` (since in this case `dist/` is the folder we are serving on Firebase hosting) and take note of the number of files in the build folder.
   [image: tree for build folder]

These should roughly be the same number of files.

Comment: For some reason this is not working with firebase version 3.15.0

Comment: I don't understand why the need to create an additional folder called `dist` instead of leaving the `public` folder to function as `dist` folder. Simply because the `dist` looks cooler or it serves other important purpose? Even the module bundler can be configured to use `public` as `dist` right?

Answer (score 2):

The ignore attribute specifies the files to ignore on deploy. It can take **glob** pattern the same way that **`Git`** handles `.gitignore`.

The following are the default values for the files to ignore:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",  // the Firebase configuration file (this file)
    "**/.*",  // files with a leading period should be hidden from the system
    "**/node_modules/**",  // contains dependencies used to create your site but not run it

    "**/someOtherFolder/**"  // this is will exclude the folder with the name entered
    "**someOtherFile**" // this will exclude that particular file
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`!(pattern)` Matches anything that does not match any of the patterns provided.

`*` Only matches files and folders in the root of the public directory

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["**, !*"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```