# firebase deploy - how to see which files are deployed and debug gcloudignore?

Tags: git, firebase, google-cloud-platform, gitignore, google-cloud-deploy

I have a `.gcloudignore` but still keep getting the error:

> Your proposed upload is larger than the maximum

Is there any way to see which files will be deployed or otherwise debug this?
A bit like `git add . -n` since it takes 10mins to try a full deploy process.

I have a layout like below.

- I've tried placing the `.gcloudignore` at the top level and also inside the functions dir.
- I've tried deploying from both within 'functions' and also from the top level.
- made sure the gcloudignore ALSO will ignore everything in `.gitignore` by using the special directive.
- made sure the `.gitignore` is available at the same level as `.gcloudignore`
- checked the `enabled` status of the `.gcloudignore`

But it still doesn't work and is preventing deployment.

```
├── cloud_tasks_emulator
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
├── firebase-debug.log
├── firebase.json
├── firestore.indexes.json
├── firestore.rules
├── functions
│   ├── lib/  <== compiled ts>js output
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── renders/  <== this local folder i'm trying to ignore
│   ├── src/  <== also i dont really want .ts src deployed
│   └── yarn.lock
├── justfile
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── storage.rules
```

And the `.gcloudignore` looks like this

```
# files to not upload to gcloud

# include the gitignore also https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore
#!include:.gitignore

.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

renders
functions/renders
renders/
```

links / related

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore
- [How can I exclude a file from deploy in gcloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751908/how-can-i-exclude-a-file-from-deploy-in-gcloud)
- [How to include files in .gcloudignore that are ignored in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751106/how-to-include-files-in-gcloudignore-that-are-ignored-in-gitignore)

Comment: Can you check this [link1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/845), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780364/18265570) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60395222/18265570)?

Comment: thanks for the links, i read through hopefully but mostly seems about noob mistakes like leaving leading spaces in an .ignore file...

Comment: Have you tried removing leading spaces? does it works?

Comment: I didn't have any leading spaces! that's a pretty silly thing to leave in a config file :/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `.gcloudignore` file is meant for only `GCP` deployment, not for `firebase` deployments. As there are no commands related to firebase in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) that you shared, only `gcloud` commands respect the `.gcloudignore` file. Hence, the files are not ignored in `firebase deploy`.

To ignore files on `firebase` deployment, you may use [`ignore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#ignore) field in the `firebase.json` file as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40245037/18265570).

To see which files will be deployed, try [ListFiles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions.files/list) endpoint, which will list remaining files to be uploaded for the specified version.

Comment: fantastic sleuthing! will try that :D